# How to convert Datetime and getting result from stored procedure in WebAPI / SQL Server

Tags: c#, entity-framework, stored-procedures, asp.net-web-api

I have the following problem. The created stored procedure needs an input value from the WebAPI. The variable contains `DateTime` as datatype. Here the created stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getDatum
    @Dt datetime
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    SELECT b.Id, b.Datum, b.num_aucts
    FROM dbo.Beispiels AS b
    WHERE b.Datum = @Dt
END
GO
```

I've added the created stored procedure to my `entity data model`. Automatically Entity Framework 6 defined code in the Context.tt for connecting to the database.

```
public virtual ObjectResult<getDatum_Result> getDatum(Nullable<System.DateTime> dt)
{
   var dtParameter = dt.HasValue ?
       new ObjectParameter("Dt", dt) :
       new ObjectParameter("Dt", typeof(System.DateTime));

       return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<getDatum_Result>("getDatum", dtParameter);
}
```

Here the defined Model `getDatum_Result`:

```
public partial class getDatum_Result
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public System.DateTime Datum { get; set; }
  public int num_aucts { get; set; }
}
```

And my Controller with the GET-Request:

```
//[ResponseType(typeof(getDatum_Result))]
public IHttpActionResult GetDatum()
{
   /*Only an example*/
   DateTime datum = new DateTime(01-03-2014);
   //getDatum_Result beispiel = db.getDatum(datum).FirstOrDefault();
   var beispiel = db.Beispiels.SqlQuery("dbo.getDatum @Dt", datum).Single();
   if (beispiel == null)
   {
      return NotFound();
   }

   return Ok(beispiel);
}
```

I don't get result from the database in my angular app, because I think either the controller is wrong or it assigns the wrong value because when I choose a date from my datepicker and send this to my stored procedure the value is `2013-01-03T23:00:00` but in the database the value is `2013-01-03T00:00:00`. Can anyone help me?

---

EDIT:

After the changes in my controller I'm getting the following error message:

> Compile Error: Ticks must be between DateTime.MinValue.Ticks and DateTime.MaxValue.Ticks. Parameter name: ticks

Comment: I suspect your your `JSON serializer` is outputting it like that. Please tell us using HTTP sniffer if the packages did got to the client side with no time only date.

Comment: @OrelEraki I don't know what you mean.. I'm using the NewtonsoftJSON serializer.. The WebAPI2 automatically de-/serialized the objects I've read in an article.

Comment: Does the `Datum` property have the right result?

Comment: @believeme It has the right datatype. I've changed the controller.. see above.

Comment: @believeme I'm getting the following error: Compile Error: Ticks must be between DateTime.MinValue.Ticks and DateTime.MaxValue.Ticks. Parameter name: ticks

Comment: Incorrect date format you must enter like this `new DateTime(2015, 01, 03);`